# jquery - p element wont show after I hid it

Tags: jquery, html, css, hide, show

im trying to build a website and ive ran into a problem. I got 4 pictures and whenever I want to click on a picture, I want it to show text. But now it wont show, however I did link it to the console log and it shows its working. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

css

```
<img class ="porfoto" title="tekstroy" id ="roy" src="img/roy.png">
<img class ="porfoto" title="tekstkinmen" id ="kinmen" src="img/kinmen.png">
<img class ="porfoto" title="tekstboris" id ="boris" src="img/boris.png">
<img class ="porfoto" title="tekstelse" id ="else" src="img/else.png">

<p id="tekstroy">hallo </p>
<p id="tekstkinmen">hallo2<p>
<p id="tekstboris">hallo3</p>
<p id="tekstelse">hallo4</p>
```

js

```
    $("#tekstroy").hide();
    $("#tekstkinmen").hide();
    $("#tekstboris").hide();
    $("#tekstelse").hide();

$(".porfoto").click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr("title");
    console.log(url)
    $(url).show();
});

$("porfoto").click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr("title");
    console.log(url)
    $(url).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

http://jsfiddle.net/L56gL/

```
$(function(){
    $("#tekstroy").hide();
    $("#tekstkinmen").hide();
    $("#tekstboris").hide();
    $("#tekstelse").hide();
});
$("img").click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr("title");
    $("p").hide();
    $("#"+url).show();
});
```

Comment: if you gave your p's a class, you could be more specific when using $("p").hide(); as that will hide all your p's

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 listeners, one shows it then immediately another one hides it.(if forgetting the '.' before portfo in the second function was a typo anyways). Also you forgot the '#'  try using `toggle` instead

```
$(".porfoto").click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr("title");
    $('#'+url).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the hash (#) for the id. Also, I'd change it from "hide"/"show" to "toggle" so that it will simply make it visible if it's hidden, and hide it if it's visible:

```
$("#tekstroy").hide();
$("#tekstkinmen").hide();
$("#tekstboris").hide();
$("#tekstelse").hide();

$(".porfoto").click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr("title");
    $('#' + url).toggle();
});
```